# Nginx multiple locations with different roots

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have really simple nginx configuration with 3 locations inside. Each of them have it's own root directory + I should be able to add another in the future easily.

**What I want:**

Request `/admin` => location `^/admin(/|$)`

Request `/admin/` => location `^/admin(/|$)`

Request `/admin/blabla` => location `^/admin(/|$)`

Request `/client` => location `^/client(/|$)`

Request `/client/` => location `^/client(/|$)`

Request `/client/blabla` => location `^/client(/|$)`

Request `/blabla` => location `/`

Request `/admin-blabla` => location `/`

Request `/client-blabla` => location `/`

**Actual result:**

All requests goes to location `/`.

I tried many different suggestions from docs, stackoverflow and other sources using different combinations of aliases, try_files, roots and regexes, but nothing worked for me.

Only when I tried to use just `return 200 'admin';` and `return 200 'front'` it worked as intended.

**Minimal config:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/www_new/front;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/admin(/|$) {
        root /var/www/html/www_new/admin;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/client(/|$) {
        root /var/www/html/www_new/client;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

**Directory structure:**

- /admin
- /client
- /front

Thank you

Comment: Do set the 'default' root at the top of your server{} block - this is a best-practice and described in [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you change the root it'll still include the directory name, so what you want to do is only set the root for `location /`. You also don't need any additional regex on `/admin` as the location modifier `~` already tells nginx 'anything starting with'.

This works for your use case:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/www_new/front;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/admin {
        root /var/www/html/www_new; # the directory (/admin) will be appended to this, so don't include it in the root otherwise it'll look for /var/www/html/www_new/admin/admin
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.html; # try_files will need to be relative to root
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to keep the whole regex in admin location, because I don't want to match eg. admin-blabla. Now the only problem is that url localhost:15000/admin is for some reason redirected to localhost/admin/ (without port).

Comment: Got ya, is `localhost:15000/admin/` also redirected (with trailing slash)?

Comment: /admin/ or /admin/blabla works fine. Problem is only without slash. Also there is nothing more in my config right now

Comment: You need to remove `$uri/` from your try files then it will no longer redirect.