# Nginx: route on localhost

Tags: nginx, routes, nginx-config

I want to configure Nginx for routing multiple projects on localhost without touching
`hosts` file on my computer.

I.e. Nginx should handle at least to paths

1. http://localhost/project-one
2. http://localhost/project-two

I found one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44480868) but it doesn't work in my case:

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.ddefault.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    # server_name  localhost;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/project-one {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/project-one;
        # index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ ^/project-two {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/project-two;
        # index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

It works if I set just one `location` to just a slash and required `root`:

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.ddefault.conf
server {
    listen       80;
    # server_name  localhost;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/project-one;
        # index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

With this config it shows html file from `project-one` directory on `http://localhost`.

I am using Docker for testing:

`docker run --rm --name my-nginx -p 80:80 -v $(pwd)/sites:/etc/nginx/conf.d -v $(pwd)/html:/usr/share/nginx/html -d nginx`

So I can change `default.conf` file for Nginx and `html` folder in local directories respectively and then restart: `docker restart my-nginx`

How to configure more than one location properly for multiple roots without touching `hosts` file?

Comment: The value of `root` is concatenated with the URI to form the path to the file. The value should be `/usr/share/nginx/html` as the `project-one` and `project-two` are part of the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith, thank you so much, it was pretty overwhelming for me until you shared this clear example with root. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally I got it...

```
server {
    listen       80;
    # server_name  localhost;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    location ~ ^/project-one {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ~ ^/project-two {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

And now it works as I expected:

`http://localhost/project-one`

`http://localhost/project-two`

Each request routes to the different folder relatively:

`/usr/share/nginx/html/project-one/index.html`

`/usr/share/nginx/html/project-two/index.html`

Thanks to @RichardSmith.